# How to learn Matplotlib without searching Google --

Tags: javascript

I am not really new to Matplotlib. I have made quite some figures with it, though I don't use it everyday (or every week, or even every month). So I tend to forget some basic things, for example, how to add a legend, how to add a color bar, how to customize a colormap, how to change the font of a specific part of the figure, how to make some transparency effect, etc. Of course, each time when I have a question, I can always google it and Google will most likely take me to stackoverflow or some other similar sites, or some blog articles, and I can almost always get a solution. This gives me an impression that the ``official'' documentation is not as useful as it should be.

But I must be wrong, namely, the official documentation must be very useful, otherwise how do those people who answer the questions know the solutions? Maybe they are ``insiders'' (developers of Matplotlib)?

So my question is, in case you are not a developer (but you are welcome to answer this question if you are), and suppose you have answered many Matplotlib-related questions here, how do you learn those techniques by yourself without asking Google? Where and how do you look for if the answer does not come to your mind immediately (not Google, because it is you who is answering that question, and before that maybe the answer does not exist in Google yet)?

Note that I am not complaining about the documentation. I think I just haven't found an efficient way to make use of it.

Or maybe finding the solution to a specific request is inevitably not straightforward due to the intrinsic complexity of Matplotlib? By intrinsic complexity, I mean in Matplotlib similar things can usually be done in many different ways, thus if one happens to choose one specific (and uncommon for whatever reasons) way in the beginning, and later comes across a problem, the solution to this problem may not have been listed explicitly in the manual, and maybe only those gurus who know how Matplotlib really works under the hood can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite confused why it's under `javascipt` ... and think it's not so good to ask on SO, Quora instead.

BTW, learn by doing works for me many times.

(I really hope I have enough reputation to add a comment instead of answer it since it has not an explicit answer)